# Selenium RC doesn't save screenshot on VMWare

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, vmware

I am running a Selenium RC (selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar) on a VMWare (Workstation 7.0.0 build-203739) Virtual Machine (Windows XP Professional SP3).

I run tests on this selenium server using Bromine. One of the tests contains a captureEntirePageScreenshot command to save a screenshot:

```
captureEntirePageScreenshot("c:/Temp/Screenshot.png", "")
```

This command is passed to Selenium server and it reports ok:

```
14:33:28.312 INFO - Command request: captureEntirePageScreenshot[C:/Temp/Screenshot.png, ] on session 1e301bb6dca4481ba007225fb4ef4f84
14:33:28.406 INFO - Got result: [base64 encoded PNG] on session 1e301bb6dca4481ba007225fb4ef4f84
14:33:30.937 INFO - Command request: testComplete[, ] on session 1e301bb6dca4481ba007225fb4ef4f84
```

But there is no screenshot in c:/Temp after this.

I have also tried captureEntirePageScreenshotToString() command, and it returns a string like this (instead of returning a base64-encoded png):

```
OR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DOCUME~1\Black\LOCALS~1\Temp\customProfileDir0be0044d90b44d63bcc746e8e6c79b10\screenshots\page-screenshot-0be0044d90b44d63bcc746e8e6c79b10.png (File not found)
```

I conclude that either Selenium or JRE that runs it (version 1.6.0_24) can't write the file to disk in order to produce the screenshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The Virtual Machine running the Selenium server has no Firewall / Antivirus software that could prevent writing to disk, it's a clean Windows XP install.

Comment: Was this working with a previous version of Selenium? It would help to identify if this is a recent regression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know, since this version of Selenium is what I started with.

Comment: A new version has been released today with many bug fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by calling [SnagIt Com Server](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/accessories/comserver.asp) from my tests (they are written in PHP). Thus, I get the ability to take screenshots in any browser, and also capture the entire page by scrolling down. So far by problem is solved. Thanks to everyone who posted answers, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue once. While upgrading my browser to FF4. This happens mostly due to firefox profile. If you are using a custom profile, delete the existing one and create a new one. If you are not using a custom profile, run the tests after creating one. That should resolve this issue.